# ASP.Net Web API 2 - ExceptionHandler vs DelegatingHandler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In Web API 2, is an exception handler supposed to replace a delegating message handler?

When is it appropriate to use delegating message handler?